# Converting chr "00:00:00" to date-time "00:00:00"

Tags: r, time, posixct, lubridate, posixlt

My question comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960517/how-to-convert-date-and-time-from-character-to-datetime-type/25960681?noredirect=1#comment40646875_25960681). The question had the following character string.

```
x <- "2007-02-01 00:00:00"
y <- "02/01/2007 00:06:10"
```

If you try to convert this string to date-class object, something funny happens.

This is a sample from @nrusell's answer.

```
as.POSIXct(x,tz=Sys.timezone())
[1] "2007-02-01 EST"

as.POSIXct(y,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",tz=Sys.timezone())
[1] "2007-02-01 00:06:10 EST"
```

As you see, `00:00:00` disappears from the first example. @Richard Scriven left the following example in our discussion using `lubridate`.

```
dt <- as.POSIXct("2007-02-01 00:00:00")
hour(dt) <- hour(dt)+1
dt
[1] "2007-02-01 01:00:00 EST"
hour(dt) <- hour(dt)-1
dt
[1] "2007-02-01 EST"
```

Once again, `00:00:00` disappears. Why does R avoid keeping `00:00:00` in date-class object after conversion? How can we keep `00:00:00`?

Comment: What's even more strange is that if you do `n <- now()` and then use `hour<-`, `minute<-` and `second<-` to take them all down to zero, midnight does actually remain.  Wackiness.  This may be an "imperfection" with date-time processing in R.

Comment: @RichardScriven: I would argue that's an imperfection in lubridate. The OP's issue isn't really an issue at all. It's similar to arguing that it's an issue that a numeric 1 doesn't print the zeros to the right of the decimal.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich But midnight is an actual time of day, so shouldn't it be printed as such?

Comment: @RichardScriven it is a fair proposition and more logic from a strictly typed view(print all the POSIXct in the same manner), but it is a convention, and since it is well documented you can remove this part also.

Comment: @RichardScriven: I agree with @agstudy. It makes sense to me to print doubles as `1.0` instead of `1` because it makes it more explicit that it's a double and not an integer. But that's the default behavior and it's documented. If you don't like it, you're free to change it. :)

Comment: Ok.  I give in.  It's there when a sequence crosses midnight so I'm happy. `x <- as.POSIXct("2014-09-10 23:59:59"); seq(x, x+2, 1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is just the `print` that remove the precision if the time part of a date is a midnight. This is literlay explained in `??strftime` help, specially the format parameter:

> A character string. The default is "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" if any
>   component has a time component which is not midnight, and "%Y-%m-%d"
>   otherwise

One idea is to redefine the S3 method `print` for POSIXct object:

```
print.POSIXct <- function(x,...)print(format(x,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Now for your example if your print your x date(with midnight part) you get:

```
x <- "2007-02-01 00:00:00"
x <- as.POSIXct(x,tz=Sys.timezone())
x
[1] "2007-02-01 00:00:00"
```

Comment: The code affecting the printing is actually in `format.POSIXlt`, which `format.POSIXct` calls, which `print.POSIXct` calls - `if (all(times[!is.na(times)] == 0)); "%Y-%m-%d";`