# Convert dates and time as characters to a date and time format

Tags: r, datetime

I have a df that contains two column with dates and time and i want to convert them from characters to date and time format. Could anyone help? Thank you

```
dput(df)
structure(list(start_date = c("2021-03-01 00:00:03", "2021-03-01 00:02:04", 
"2021-03-01 00:02:29"), finish_date = c("2021-03-01 00:16:29", 
"2021-03-01 00:35:40", "2021-03-01 00:33:14")), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

i have tried this but didnt work

```
 as.Date.POSIXct(df$start_date, format="%Y/%m/%dT%H:%M:%S"

 as.Date.POSIXct(df$finish_date, format="%Y/%m/%dT%H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: The `anytime` package can help you automagically trying a number of sensible formats.

Answer (score 0):

```
as.POSIXct('2021-03-01 00:03:04')
```

see: [past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960517/how-to-convert-date-and-time-from-character-to-datetime-type)

Comment: could you use `dput(df)` and paste R's output into your question? This is to make a re-producible dataset

Comment: i used the dput(df) to make the things easier. Could you help with the exact code I need to use in this dataframe to get the desired result? thank you

Comment: `df <- lapply(df, \(i) as.POSIXct(i))` works with the data you provided
I ran `lapply(df, class)` to check all columns' class which returned `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`

Comment: Use the below to apply to specific columns:
`x <- c('start_date', 'finish_date'); 
df[x] <- lapply(df[x], \(i) as.POSIXct(i))`